# How do I use index number as x in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out.  I have a dataframe where the row names are created automatically as just index numbers, like the sample below.

```
> df
    employee salary  startdate
1   John Doe  21000 2010-11-01
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14
```

I would like to plot this out using the row names at the x axis, but since it doesn't have a name, I can't figure this out.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could do `employ.data$indx <- row.names(employ.data)` and then use `indx` as your `x` in `ggplot`...

Comment: What is  the `ggplot` command you are using and how are you using it? You may also be able to include the rownames in the `aes()`. For example `ggplot(employ.data, aes(rownames(employ.data), salary))`

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear to me. Not sure why closed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not all clear for me (what is mapped to y? ) but

```
df <- structure(list(employee = c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope"),
                     salary = c(21000L, 23400L, 26800L),
                     startdate = c("2010-11-01", "2008-03-25", "2007-03-14")),
                .Names = c("employee", "salary", "startdate"),
                row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
# if row.names are strings
df$idu <- row.names(df)
# if row numbers are integers (most likely!)
df$idu <- as.numeric(row.names(df))

df

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x=idu, y = salary), data = df) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

or use the suggestion from @MrFlick without the idu column

```
ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(row.names(df)), y = salary), data = df) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  labs(x='ID')
```

[image: geom_bar]

Comment: So this is what I was trying to do, but figured there wouldn't need to create a new column based on the rownames.

Comment: @CptanPanic use the 2nd example, as suggested by MrFlick

Comment: If there are more than 9 rows, one needs to convert the row names to numbers: `as.numeric(row.names(df))`.  Otherwise, the sorting does not work correctly.

Comment: @jarauh yes, true

Comment: `x = 1:nrow(df)` ?